how to export same font for both base and ggplot2 plots, in R?
I am trying to understand how to make sure the font i am exporting from both base and ggplot2 plots is the same. The best would be to be able to have all plots from ggplot2 but for some reason, one plot i need to do with base R. I wrote an example code that exports svg for both ggplot and base r. I found a previous post suggesting the font that is normally used by base R is Helvetica. For ggplot it seems more tricky.
The first link suggests to have a look at available fonts. Here the output:
> X11Fonts()
$serif
[1] "-*-times-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$sans
[1] "-*-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$mono
[1] "-*-courier-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Times
[1] "-adobe-times-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Helvetica
[1] "-adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$CyrTimes
[1] "-cronyx-times-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$CyrHelvetica
[1] "-cronyx-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Arial
[1] "-monotype-arial-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

$Mincho
[1] "-*-mincho-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*"

This is the code i am using to export the plots as svg images:
# load libraries
library("ggplot2")

# declare function to export plots
export_svg <- function(filename, a_plot, base=FALSE) {

# if plot is made with ggplot2
if (base==F) {
    # plot
    svg(filename, width=10, height=10)
        plot(a_plot)
    dev.off()
# else with base R
} else {
    # plot
    svg(filename, width=10, height=10)
        a_plot
    dev.off()
}
}

# declare plotting function for base plots
base_plot <- function(df){

    par(mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2))
    plot(df$x, df$y, xlim=c(-5, 10), ylim=c(-5, 10))
    text(df$x, df$y, labels=df$label)
}

# declare plotting function for ggplot
ggplot_plot <- function(df) {

    ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + geom_text(aes(label=label),hjust=0, vjust=0) + xlim(-5, 10) + ylim(-5, 10) + theme_bw()
}

# create a basic data frame
df <- data.frame(x=c(1, 3, 7), y=c(2, 4, 6), label=c("a_label", "a_second_label", "a_third_label"))

# export base
export_svg("base.svg", base_plot(df), base=TRUE)

# export ggplot
export_svg("ggplot.svg", ggplot_plot(df), base=FALSE)

How do i make sure if the two fonts exported are the same font? They may be the same, but the look slightly different, which may be a problem related to the exporting of pdfs, as suggested by the developer of extrafont. It seems, to me, that svg suffers from the same problem. Do you have any ideas?

I dont see a difference apart from the size of the font, because the way the different plotting platforms perform their layouts. you could play around with scaling the base plot up or down with the cex param, to try to match. but this may be an x/y problem; what stops you from producing the plot you want in ggplot2 along with the others ?

@NirGraham, i agree, the two fonts seem to be the same which is good. i also agree that best would be to have everything in ggplot2. what stops me doing the plot is theme for another question (i need a biplot for ecology studies and i am unable to reproduce the same results i get with base, by using ggplot2). i will consider asking a separate question.
